# Electrical Engineering needs a Markdown solution for overline

Tags: feature-request, markdown

The [introduction of tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) was a great addition to the [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) substack, since I often want to quote tables from electronic component datasheets. An actual table is far more functional than a screenshot of a table even if it often takes up more room.

But now that I start converting screenshots into real tables I see a pressing need to render text with [overline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline#Engineering) which is used to denote that a signal is [inverted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level#Active_state). It is very common when discussing topics in electrical engineering, and I have not found a way to do it on Stack Exchange.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve. Note the bar over the text CS/LD in the first column:

[image: Example of table text with an overline]

According to the answers to the question *[Is there a way to overline text in (GitHub flavoured) Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087009/is-there-a-way-to-overline-text-in-github-flavoured-markdown)* there could be two or three ways to solve this, but I've found that neither works well.

#### text-decoration:overline

Quoted: `<span style="text-decoration:overline">RESET</span>`
Rendered: RESET

This would be the preferred method, but it seems to be filtered out by the renderer and I can't see why. The quote from *[We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)* seems to be false:

> I’ve prepared a feature that will swap out our current, home-grown Markdown renderers with well-tested open-source implementations that adhere to the CommonMark specification. For the curious: this means we’re replacing PageDown with **markdown-it** on the client side and MarkdownSharp with **markdig** on the server side.

[markdig](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig)'s output on [Babelmark](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22text-decoration%3Aoverline%22%3Ereset%3C%2Fspan%3E%0A) renders this correctly. So does the [CommonMark reference implementation](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/).

[markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) strips HTML tags by default, but the output on Babelmark does not look like the preview here.

#### Unicode Combining Overline

Unicode lets you add a [Combining Overline](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0305) to each character, but this is not optimal:

- They are designed to modify a single letter and will create gaps when used for a word
- Rendering seems to be implementation defined and also utterly broken on some systems: *[Why is Unicode combining character order different between IDEA and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621353/why-is-unicode-combining-character-order-different-between-idea-and-chrome)*

#### MathJax

Where MathJax is enabled you can use something like `$\rm\overline{RESET}$`. This changes the font, adds a lot of unnecessary complexity, and only works on a few select sites.

Comment: The SE team does also check per-site metas for feature requests and bug reports, not only this site, so if this is truly specific to EE.SE you should post on their meta.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog I considered that but decided to post here for two reasons. 1. Every time someone asks about a feature on the EE meta the answer is always "Rendering is site-wide so we can't change anything", and 2. This would be useful for any site dealing with electronics, logic, and mathematics, so I thought I'd start here.

Comment: Related [Next math renderer MathJax v3 versus KaTeX?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338933/289691), [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

Comment: There's over [500 overline questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=overline) already, and as [you can see, MathJax tables are trivial](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1245/142621) to compose and easy to read; example at the end shows it adds three lines to the data.

Comment: O̅v̅e̅r̅l̅i̅n̅e̅ ̅e̅x̅a̅m̅p̅l̅e̅ - generated by:   https://fsymbols.com/generators/overline/ - there's more than one site that offers that service.

Comment: @Rob I covered the MathJax hack and the unicode-version in the actual question. I also mentioned how broken it is. What is the point of your comment? It doesn't render correctly in many browsers.

Comment: pipe, the "point" of my comment is: many people already have worked around the problem. --- Using MathJax ***correctly*** doesn't produce an unusable font, and it can easily be stored in an HTML comment on non-MathJax sites. --- I suggest that you offer a more convincing reason to assign the time and expense of having a developer perfect what you perceive as less than perfect results; that are already accepted by 1000's of people. Stack Exchange requires strong reason to spend the money. You are welcome to leave your Feature Request as-is, and reject offered advice; it's common practice.

Comment: Eh. Its in the spec, there might be sites other than EE that could use it. I'd totally see myself status-reviewing this if I knew its something the devs were working on. There is *no* good reason to throw cold water on this feature request.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't think it's in the spec. I don't think the spec covers much styling at all - markdown is mostly converting to HTML; CSS doesn't really enter the equation. The effect wanted here, though, is a question of styling. The reason it works for the implementations mentioned here is the CSS class involved having that effect.

Comment: Also related meta post: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/241919): because the `<span>` tag is not supported, so while it might be rendered on the client, it will be stripped on the server anyway.