# Why isn't xcolor supported for Latex?

Tags: support, mathjax, latex

In mathcha.io, I have an equation with colors.

[image: equation with colors]

```
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X} =\ \textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.01,0.11}{\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}} W^{T}
\end{equation*}
```

If I want to paste the Latex code into https://stats.stackexchange.com/, it doesn't work.
[image: posted question]

On overleaf.com, the same thing happens and I need to add `\usepackage{xcolor}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X} =\ \textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.01,0.11}{\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}} W^{T}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

However, we can't import packages in stats.stackexchange.
[image: document syntax]

I am wondering if there is another way to add colors or whether there is a reason why colors aren't supported.

Comment: **To close voters:** This question is asking about MathJax, a feature that is supported on multiples Stack Exchange sites. It should *not* be closed as "only applicable to one site".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\color{blue}` markup. This seems to be the supported way to include color in your MathJax, based on the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/10116#10116)

I'm not sure if you're allowed to use extra packages. At least the ones I tried didn't work for me. That would explain why `\usepackage{xcolor}` doesn't work.

Run the below code snippet to see the color in action. (because Meta Stack Exchange doesn't have MathJax enabled)

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>

<div>
$$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial X} =\ \color{blue}{\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}} W^{T}
\end{equation*}
$$
</div>
```

Comment: Well that doesn't answer the "why".

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard now it does, kind of

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported because Stack Exchange is using old version of MathJax, and not upgrading it.

Stack Exchange is using version 2.7.5 while the latest stable version is 3.2.2, hence it's expected that many features won't be available in Stack Exchange.

It was [asked already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338933/next-math-renderer-mathjax-v3-versus-katex) to upgrade MathJax, three and half years ago, to no avail. Sadly, there's nothing we can do except upvote that request, and pray to *[put your deity name here]* to make a miracle.